# How to Use Picklist Value to Formula in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, picklist

I have a custom field picklist with field name `CompanyClassify__c`(★) including values: `Government offices／Group companies／Listed company／Listed subsidiary／Other`.
I have a custom number field with field name `CalcLevelNum__c`(★★) and want to calculate the value based on (★)'s selection.
For example:
If (★) is selected as `Government offices`, 20 will be taken plus the value entered in another custom number field,
If (★) is selected as `Listed company`, 36 will be taken plus the value entered in another custom number field.

At that time, in the Default Value section of (★★) I set up the following formula but got the error:
`Error: Field CompanyClassify__c may not be used in this type of formula`

My formula is as follows:

```
CASE (CompanyClassify__c,
"Government offices",20 + LevelNum__c,
"Group companies",20 + LevelNum__c,
"Listed company",36 + LevelNum__c,
"Listed subsidiary",48 + LevelNum__c,
"Other",60 + LevelNum__c)
```

■■■UPDATE

```
CASE(TEXT(CompanyClassify__c),
    "Government offices",20,
    "Group companies",20,
    "Listed company",36,
    "Listed subsidiary",48,
    60
)
+ LevelNum__c
```

[image]

Because I'm newbie of Salesforce, I don't know what the error is and how to fix the formula.
Can anyone Help ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Original answer

Picklists are historically bit funny in formulas. You need either

`IF(ISPICKVAL(CompanyClassify__c, 'Government Offices'), do_something_if_true, do_something_if_false)`

Or if you want to use them in a CASE statement / flatten them to their string representation with `TEXT(CompanyClassify__c)`

So for your scenario I think this would be simplest

```
CASE(TEXT(CompanyClassify__c),
    "Government offices",20,
    "Group companies",20,
    "Listed company",36,
    "Listed subsidiary",48,
    60
)
+ LevelNum__c
```

---

### Edit

Ah, you're doing it in a "default field value" formula. I thought you want a real new formula field (of type formula, not of type number). Won't work, the defaults are calculated just once when the "new" page renders. There's no fancy "as I change 1 field recalculate other fields" in UI, at least not without custom coding. The defaults must be hardcoded or can depend on who's looking (like based on some field read from user record) but can't depend on other fields.

Do you need this new field to be editable, overridable by user? Or is it a hard mapping rule?

If it's "hard" I'd say delete this field and make new one with same name but type = "Formula" and on next page you specify subtype = number. Nice and easy.

If you want it to be editable, overridable by the user you'll need to go back to business and get some more logic from them. Once overridden - does it stay overridden even if `CompanyClassify__c` or `LevelNum__c` changes? Or on change they "win" and wipe the override? If user changes all 3 (classify, level and calculate level number) - the level number entered by the user should win?

One (fairly simple) way would be to have a `Level number override` number field. And then your formula would be

```
BLANKVALUE(Level_Number_Override__c,
    CASE(TEXT(CompanyClassify__c),
        "Government offices",20,
        "Group companies",20,
        "Listed company",36,
        "Listed subsidiary",48,
        60
    )
    + LevelNum__c
)
```

if user entered something - it wins, else fallback. Easy to write, test and report on "records with overrides" to spot any issues.

So 4 fields total: company classify (picklist), level num (number), calculate level (formula), calculate level override (number)

If you need something fancier that changes the `Calculate_Level_Number__c` when `CompanyClassify__c` or `LevelNum__c` change (unless user changed the Calculate_Level_Number__c` too in same edit) - you're looking at some simple proper automation like "early flow" or an apex trigger.

Comment: Thank you for your support. I updated it using the formula as you instructed but the error is still the same. I have added images to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Hello  CompanyClassify__c can't be used inside the context where you are trying to use it.

I think you need to go with this solution **Workflow Rules, Process Builder, Apex**.

I had take the reference from following links
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/107873/process-builder-vs-scheduled-apex

Comment: Is this from chatgpt? Very low quality